# Choose icon options in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I would like to present the user of my iPhone app with 3 icons. They should touch one and the other two will become shaded. If they then touch one of the other ones, that one becomes illuminated normally and the other two darken.

What is the best way to do this in Interface Builder/ Cocoa-Touch?

Thanks :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem using Segmented Control button.